# Java BinarySearch(двоичный поиск)

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, поиск

Здравствуйте, я изучаю язык Java и написал программу **бинарного поиска**, однако возникла проблема. Когда **символа**, который нужно найти, в **массиве** не существует, программа попадает в **бесконечный цикл**, и я никак не могу придумать выход из этой ситуации. Вот код моей программы

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[]arr = {'a','d','f','l','o','z'};
        find(arr,'m');

    }
    public static void find(char[]arr,char ch){
        int last = arr.length-1;
        int mid=last;
        while (arr[mid] != ch){
            if (arr[mid]<ch){
                mid = (last+mid)/2;
            }
            else{
               last=mid;
                mid=last/2;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(mid);
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подправил:

```
public static void find(char[] arr, char ch) {
    int last = arr.length - 1;
    int first = 0;
    int mid = (last + 1) / 2;
    while (arr[mid] != ch && last != mid && first != mid) {
        if (arr[mid] < ch) {
            first = mid;
            mid = (last + first) / 2;
        } else {
            last = mid;
            mid = (last + first) / 2;
        }
    }
    if (arr[last] == ch)
        mid = last;
    if (arr[first] == ch)
        mid = first;
    System.out.print(arr[mid] == ch ? mid : "Elem not found");
}
```

Вам не хватало проверки граничных элементов и указателя на начало проверяемого промежутка.

Comment: Я проверил ваше решение, оно к сожалению не работает, когда я ввожу найти букву "z", программа выводит "Elem not found"

Comment: @EgorovEgor, теперь выводит

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь все понял.